# Haskell:update a binary tree

Tags: dictionary, haskell, binary-tree

I want to implement a map function ,mapLeaves ,which a function only map to the leaves in binary tree.And return a updated tree.

```
data Tree = TNode Int [Tree] | Tleaf Int

    
         -1
        /   \
      -5     10
      / \   
    -4  30  
    / \
   13  17

t = TNode (-1) [TNode (-5)  [  TNode (-4) [ Tleaf 13, Tleaf 17] ,  Tleaf 30 ] ,Tleaf 10 ]

getListLeaves (Tleaf x)= [x]
getListLeaves (TNode x [Tleaf y])=[y]
getListLeaves (TNode x (y:ys))=  (getListLeaves y) ++ (getListLeaves (TNode x ys)) 

mapLeaves f tree = map (f) (getListLeaves tree)
```

> mapLeaves (+3) t
> and get the answer
> [16,20,33,13]

this is where i stop,how can i make this List to a binary tree ,just as the t shown above,which leaves got updated but node remains.
Thanks in advance.

Edited:
Why is this works,

```
sumLeaves :: Tree -> Int
sumLeaves (Tleaf x)=x
sumLeaves (TNode n xs)=sum (map sumLeaves xs)
```

but when i change sum to TNode n it does not works,

```
sumLeaves :: Tree -> Int
sumLeaves (Tleaf x)=x
sumLeaves (TNode n xs)=TNode n (map sumLeaves xs)
```

and also this is where i stuck,

```
mapLeaves :: (Int -> Int) -> Tree -> Tree
mapLeaves f (Tleaf x) = Tleaf (f x)
mapLeaves f (TNode x cs)=TNode x  (map mapLeaves f cs)
```

Comment: Don't use a list in the first place. Right now the "information about the structure" is lost. use recursion to map the elements in the tree.

Comment: ok, i solved it ,thanks and i am really stupid ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a list in the first place. Right now the "information about the structure" is lost. use recursion to map the elements in the tree.

You thus can implement this as:

```
mapLeaves :: (Int -> Int) -> Tree -> Tree
mapLeaves f (Tleaf x) = …
mapLeaves f (TNode x cs) = TNode x (…)
```

where you need to fill in the `…` parts. For the `TNode` part you thus create a new `TNode` with `x` as value and you recurse on the children of the tree `cs`.

The modeling is however a bit odd. While one can represent a binary tree, the data type does not *enforce* a binary tree: since a `TNode` can have zero, one, or more children. Furthermore a `TNode` with no children is probably a leaf, but you have an extra data constructor for that, which thus means that the same (binary) tree, can be represented in multiple ways, which is often not a good idea.